# Failed to get fields from a class that extends SpringSecurity User class (in a Grails project)

Tags: grails, spring-security, field, extends

I have 2 childs class that extends the SpringSecurity User class in a Grails project. Example:

```
class MyUserOne extends User {
   def email
   def address
}

class MyUserTwo extends User {
   def company
   def town
}
```

I create some MyUserOne and MyUserTwo objects in the BootStrap and i save them to the test database, but... When i logged like a MyUserOne user, and trying to access in a .gsp file to the *email* field:

```
<sec:loggedInUserInfo field="email"/>
```

it throws an exception saying that "email" is not a property of the class User, and it's true, but, how can i access to the fields of the child classes? I "solved" this with this code fragment:

```
def user = springSecurityService.currentUser
[userInstance: user]
```

in any controller, and then i can access to the field

```
${userInstance.email}
```

... but doing this i have the same user object twice (*userInstance* and *springSecurityService*, **i think it's not the correct way**.

Is there any solution?

Thanks

Comment: Have you customized your UserDetailsService and UserDetails objects? You are getting the error because 'email' isn't part of the UserDetails object stored in the session.

Comment: @uchamp is right. see http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/11%20Custom%20UserDetailsService.html

Comment: I didnt customize UserDetailsService and UserDetails objects, im going to try this.

In this case, UserDetails will be my MyUserOne class, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you specified the Class which should springSecurity use as the User object?

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.project.MyUserOne'
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. If i specify MyUserOne as a DomainClassName, then I'll not be able to login as a MyUserTwo user. Or... can i have 2 classes like userDomainClassName?

grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.project.MyUserOne'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.project.MyUserTwo'

Comment: I am not sure. I have never used 2 different User models like this. In this case I would go with uchamp's comment. You will have to define your own UserDetails Object and build it based on the subclass.